# How to accumulate elements in a list using Reap and Sow

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Does anybody know how to rewrite this fragment using Reap and Sow instead of AppendTo. I need to reduce the execution time. Thank you.

```
list = {};
T = 10^3;
p = 0.5;

AbsoluteTiming[

 Do[

  AppendTo[list, {}];

  If[i > 10,

   AppendTo[list[[i]], RandomReal[]];

   Do[

    If[RandomReal[] >= p,

      AppendTo[list[[j]], RandomReal[]];

      ];

    , {j, 1, i}];

   ];

  , {i, 1, T}]
 ]
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? `AbsoluteTiming[
 Last@Reap@Do[
    Sow[{}];
    If[i > 10,
     Sow[RandomReal[]];
     Do[
      If[RandomReal[] >= p,
       Sow[RandomReal[]]
       ],
      {j, 1, i}]
     ],
    {i, 1, T}
    ]
 ]`

Comment: Just for clarity `Do[If[RandomReal[] >= p, AppendTo[list[[j]], RandomReal[]];];, {j, 1, 
  i}]` is not the same random real each time. Is that intended? It seems like this could be reconstructed by sampling a large list of random numbers

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?  Why do you want to AppendTo[list, {}]?  I think if you describe the desired output list there will be very simple code to achieve it rapidly.

Comment: I answered this question at [your older question about directed Barabasi-Albert](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71737/how-to-implement-the-directed-barabasi-albert-algorithm-in-mathematica).